# How can I auto box this class?

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing

I've the following class:

```
public class IntegerKey extends Number implements Comparable<IntegerKey> {

    private Integer m_key;

    public IntegerKey(Integer key) {
        m_key = key;
    }

    public IntegerKey(int key) {
        m_key = key;
    }

}
```

I would like to use this class as Follow:

assume I have the following generics:

```
Map<IntegerKey, MyCache> map = new HashMap<IntegerKey, MyCache>();

map.put(5, new MyCache());
```

This doesn't compile, why?? I don't want to do:

```
map.put(new IntegerKey(5), new MyCache());
```

Thank you.

Comment: 5 is an int, not a IntegerKey. Can't you use int/Integer instead of IntegerKey?

Answer (score 5):

> This doesn't compile, why?

Because there's no implicit conversion from `int` to `IntegerKey`. You can't create user-defined implicit conversions in Java. You're stuck with the ones defined by the language.

You've *either* got to explicitly get hold of a `IntegerKey` somehow, or you've got to change the type of your map to `Map<Integer, MyCache>`.

Answer (score 2):

> This doesn't compile, why??

Only primitive types are auto-boxed to their wrappers. Not other combinations are allowed in Java.

> I don't want to do:

```
map.put(new KeyInteger(5), new MyCache());
```

In that case don't use a KeyInteger, just use an Integer.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with this option of allocating new IntegerKey whenever I would like to access this map.

Comment: Or you can use `Integer` like we all suggested. :P

Comment: @user1720101 You could use a static factory method that pools `KeyInteger` instances. This is what `Integer.valueOf` does.

Answer (score 2):

Autoboxing only works for the primitives types and their respective counter parts in `java.lang`. In your example you could try dropping `IntegerKey` altogether and simply use `Integer`.

Comment: The example I gave is only partial. this IntegerKey class holds more data-members and logic inside.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the comment concerning the special functionality of `IntegerKey`, it seems logical to wrap the functionality you are asking for in a new class (MHashMap in the following examples):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class IntegerKey extends Number implements Comparable<IntegerKey> {
  private Integer m_key;
  public IntegerKey(Integer key) {
    m_key = key;
  }

  public IntegerKey(int key) {
    m_key = key;
  }
  //...Functionality
  //...required methods to include to actually test
  @Override
  public int compareTo (IntegerKey arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public double doubleValue () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public float floatValue () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int intValue () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public long longValue () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

}
class MyCache {}
class MHashMap extends HashMap<IntegerKey, MyCache> {
  public void put (int key, MyCache value) {
    super.put(new IntegerKey(key), value);
  }
  public void put (Integer key, MyCache value) {
    super.put(new IntegerKey(key), value);
  }
  //...Useful to include other wrappings
  public MyCache get (int key) {
    return super.get(new IntegerKey(key));
  }
  public MyCache get (Integer key) {
    return super.get(new IntegerKey(key));
  }
}
public class AutoboxFix {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    //needed to explicitly declare map as MHashMap for "override" to work
    MHashMap map = new MHashMap();
    //compiles
    map.put(5, new MyCache());
    //... get probably works with your extended functionality
  }
}
```

This should provide the functionality your looking for. The get method will depend on the methods in `Comparable`.  There may be more methods that you want to reimplement to auto cast from `int` or `Integer` to `IntegerKey`, but you should be able to use the rest of the HashMap functionality normally.  It is necessary to declare map as `MHashMap` type, because using `Map` won't compile. It would be sensible to separate classes into their own files and make them public.

This approach won't work if it's absolutely necessary to declare map as `Map<IntegerKey, MyCache>`. You could make a static method where ever your using map and such to do the casting for you:

```
public class AClass {
  public static void myPutMethod (Map<Integer, MyCache> map, int key,
       MyCache value) {
    map.put(new IntegerKey(key), value);
  }
}
```

Use:

```
myPutMethod(map, 5, new MyCache());
```

Then you can define more methods for `Integer` and `Map.get`.